# Specific terminal commands stopped working

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, command

I get the following error message when trying to run certain commands from my terminal:

```
zsh: command not found: <command name>
```

Commands that don't work include:

```
pip
virtualenv
jupyter
```

Additionally importing sklearn into python files throws an error message as well:

```
>     ImportError: No module named sklearn.preprocessing
>     [shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/michellehackl/Google Drive/Work/2017 Summer Internship/GitHub/ud120-projects/k_means/k_means_cluster.py"]
>     [dir: /Users/michellehackl/Google Drive/Work/2017 Summer Internship/GitHub/ud120-projects/k_means]
>     [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Commands that do work:

```
git
ls, cd, open, etc.
```

Tried so far:

- uninstall oh-my-zsh
- manually change PATH variable in .bash_profile and .zshrc file
- reset both using ~source/

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS is not installed with Python tools like `pip`, `virtualenv` or `jupyter`.

Follow the respective documentation for:

- [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/),
- [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/),
- [Jupyter](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: All of these should be installed. I installed them and used them before. They just stopped working ~2 days ago.

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I checked the PATH variable in the bash_profile and when running export it returns that variable.

Comment: PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" This is my path variable, exactly as described in that Wikipedia page

Comment: @Lyyoness: Are `pip`, `virtualenv` and `Jupiter` installed in any of this directories? Certainly not… So: one path is missing and/or you need to install them.